# Nontype template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, parameters

I'm having trouble with nontype(int variable) template parameter.
Why can't I pass a constant int variable to a function and let the function instantiate the template?

```
template<int size>
class MyTemplate
{
  // do something with size
};

void run(const int j)
{
  MyTemplate<j> b; // not fine
}
void main()
{
  const int i = 3;
  MyTemplate<i> a; // fine;
  run(i); // not fine
}
```

not fine : compiler says, error: 'j' cannot appear in constant-expression

- EDIT

This is what I ended up with.
Maybe someone might use it, someone might suggest better way.

```
enum PRE_SIZE
{
    PRE_SIZE_256 = 256,
    PRE_SIZE_512 = 512,  
    PRE_SIZE_1024 = 1024,
};

template<int size>
    class SizedPool : public Singleton< SizedPool<size> >
{
public:
    SizedPool()
        : mPool(size)
    {
    }
    void* Malloc()
    {
        return mPool.malloc();
    }

    void Free(void* memoryPtr)
    {
        mPool.free(memoryPtr);
    }

private:
    boost::pool<>       mPool;
};

template<int size>
    void* SizedPoolMalloc()
    {
        return SizedPool<size>::GetInstance()->Malloc();
    }

template<int size>
    void SizedPoolFree(void* memoryPtr)
    {
        SizedPool<size>::GetInstance()->Free(memoryPtr);
    }

void* SizedPoolMalloc(int size)
{
    if (size <= PRE_SIZE_256)
        return SizedPoolMalloc<PRE_SIZE_256>();
    else if (size <= PRE_SIZE_512)
        return SizedPoolMalloc<PRE_SIZE_512>();
}


void toRun(const int j)
{
    SizedPoolMalloc(j);
}
void Test17()
{
    const int i = 3;
    toRun(i);
}
```

Comment: Shortly, because, the template arguments must be known by compiler at compile time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because non-type template parameters require values at compile-time. Remember that templates are a compile-time mechanism; templates do not exist in the final executable. Also remember that functions and the passing of arguments to functions are runtime mechanisms. The value of the `j` parameter in `run()` will not be known until the program actually runs and invokes the `run()` function, well past after the compilation stage.

```
void run(const int j)
{
    // The compiler can't know what j is until the program actually runs!
    MyTemplate<j> b;
}

const int i = 3;
run(i);
```

That's why the compiler complains says "'j' cannot appear in constant-expression".

On the other hand, this is fine because the value of `i` is known at compile-time.

```
const int i = 3;
// The compiler knows i has the value 3 at this point,
// so we can actually compile this.
MyTemplate<i> a;
```

You can pass compile-time values to run-time constructs, but not the other way around.

However, you can have your `run()` function accept a non-type template parameter the same way your `MyTemplate` template class accepts a non-type template parameter:

```
template<int j>
void run()
{
    MyTemplate<j> b;
}

const int i = 3;
run<i>();
```

Comment: umm, I thought since i is defined at compile time and passing it to run(), it would be compile time constant. Is there a work around to this? (Since it seems a common requirement)

Comment: @Eugene: Remember that invoking a function and passing arguments to a function is a runtime mechanism. The function body of `run()` cannot possibly know that `j` is in fact a compile-time constant. What if `run()` was defined in a totally different source file? In a different library or application?

Comment: wow I just did what you are suggesting(although in a dummy class, didn't know I could just define template function outside class). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Basically, C++ has two kinds of constants:

```
const int a = 5;
MyTemplate<a> foo; // OK

const int b = rand();
MyTemplate<b> foo; // Not OK.
```

The first example is a compile-time constant. In C++ standard speak, it's an Integral Constant Expression (ICE). The second example is a run-time constant. It has the same C++ type (`const int`) but it's not an ICE.

Your function `void run(const int j)` is a run-time constant. You could even pass in user input. Therefore it's not a valid template argument.

The reason for the rule is that the compiler must generate code based on the template argument value. It can't do so if it doesn't have a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

Because j should be known at compile time. In your example it is not.